# Best way to search this type of database structure?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, structure

This is an example of my database structure, I would like to know the best and fastest way to create a search function.

orders_users Table:

```
id || order_id || title || first_name || last_name || email || telephone
```

orders_details Table:

```
id || transaction_id || date_time || status
```

Currently I do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_users WHERE last_name = '%QUERY%'
```

After this I do a PHP foreach on the results of the first query to query the date_time and status from the second table. (which is necessary for my search results page)

```
SELECT * FROM orders_details WHERE id = '%ORDER_ID FROM FIRST QUERY%'
```

This is fine for uncommon names but if I do a search for 'smith' on about 80k rows it is understandably slow.

The only other way I've thought of is to populate a separate table with searchable columns and results which would only require the one query, like this:

```
id || order_id || last_name || date_time || status
```

I'd prefer not to go down this route if possible as I don't really want to be updating multiple tables with the same data.

I'm sure my head's not thinking straight on this one, I just need a bit of guidance.

Comment: This looks like a job for JOIN

Comment: @SamHuckaby I agree. Are these tables supposed to be part of a *relational* database? If so, would that mean that they share a common `id` column, or ?

Comment: Have you thought about indexing the common columns?

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for the quick replies, JOIN works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always join two tables together by:

```
SELECT O.id as id, D.id as order_id, last_name, date_time, status 
FROM orders_users as O LEFT JOIN orders_details as D 
ON O.id = D.id
WHERE last_name LIKE '%QUERY%'
```

Searching in sql is very quick, so you do not have to worry about the speed of spl search.
Just in case, if you only want to search by only last_name, I recommend you to add index to this column, it helps searching speed but not insertion or deletion speed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [learn how learn how `JOIN`s work](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
SELECT u.order_id, u.last_name, d.date_time, d.status
FROM orders_users u INNER JOIN orders_details d
  ON u.order_id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use an *inner join* like below.

```
SELECT ou.id, 
       ou.order_id, 
       ou.last_name, 
       od.date_time, 
       od.status 
  FROM orders_users ou
 INNER JOIN orders_details od 
    ON od.id = ou.order_id 
 WHERE ou.last_name = '%QUERY%'
```